# Connection error in WSL2 when connecting to Mongo

Tags: mongodb, ip, firewall, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a POC account for MongoDB cloud which I am trying to connect to using mongo shell.
After providing pass I get below error. Converting back to WSL1 is a fix but I would rather stay on WSL2.

When I do simple `ping google.com` everything seems to be working ok.

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.8
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb+srv://yyyy-yyy-yyyy.yyyyy.mongodb.net/node_db
2020-11-28T13:20:18.780+0100 I NETWORK  [thread1] Starting new replica set monitor for atlas-qtxfdg-shard-0/yyyy-yyy-shop-yyy-00-02.yyyy.mongodb.net.:27017,yyyy-yyy-yyyy-shard-00-00.yyyyy.mongodb.net.:27017,yyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-00-01.yyyyy.mongodb.net.:27017
2020-11-28T13:20:23.848+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 20.67.41.218:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2020-11-28T13:20:23.914+0100 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Failed to connect to 20.56.152.73:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2020-11-28T13:20:28.940+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 20.61.168.228:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2020-11-28T13:20:28.940+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Unable to reach primary for set atlas-qtxfdg-shard-0
2020-11-28T13:20:28.940+0100 I NETWORK  [thread1] Cannot reach any nodes for set atlas-qtxfdg-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
2020-11-28T13:20:34.449+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 20.67.41.218:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2020-11-28T13:20:39.459+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 20.61.168.228:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2020-11-28T13:20:44.468+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 20.56.152.73:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2020-11-28T13:20:44.468+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Unable to reach primary for set atlas-qtxfdg-shard-0
2020-11-28T13:20:44.468+0100 I NETWORK  [thread1] Cannot reach any nodes for set atlas-qtxfdg-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 2 checks in a row.
2020-11-28T13:20:44.471+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: connect failed to replica set atlas-qtxfdg-yyyy-0/yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyy-00-02.yyyyyy.mongodb.net.:27017,yyyy-yyyy-yyy-yyyyy-00-00.yyyyy.mongodb.net.:27017,yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-00-01.yyyyyy.mongodb.net.:27017 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: try upgrading mongoDB; if your server is running it may have to do with the +srv string hence the last line "`connect@src/`". You could try the old way: `mongo "mongodb://ID1:port1,ID2:port2,ID3:port3/<dbname>?replicaSet=nameHere" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username USER --password PASS`

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.4.1, MongoDB server version: 4.2.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue was with firewall setting in Avast.

Solution I found: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/481 states:

`go to Settings -> Protection -> Firewall -> Check the "Internet Connection Sharing Mode".`

Answer (score 1):

Check in Windows settings if the network is public or private, firewall configuration may be different for each one (usually with more restrictions for public networks). I had connection issues with Mongo Atlas from WSL 2 and it was because of having the network as public, so some Node JS operations were being blocked by the firewall (Windows Defender in my setup).